# Django: How to test a not-null field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to make an unit test fail when a not-null field is not set in my model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        null=False,
        blank=False)

def testFoo(self):
    try:
        Foo.objects.create().save()
    except:
        self.fail("error!")
```

But it never fails.

The email format and not-null validations work perfectly when the application is running but I can't write the test.

Of course I can do the validations programmatically but I don't want to repeat myself. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the right way is `Foo().save()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you have a few issues, let me enumerate:

1. The `save` is superfluous. `create` already does the save.
2. Creating objects does not trigger validation of things like "is this email a valid email". If you tried to pass in `email=None` it would fail because of your `null=False` parameter to the field, but the default for email is `''`, so it's not failing at that level. If you want to validate whether the email is valid or not, do this:

   ```
   def testFoo(self):
       try:
           a = Foo.objects.create()
           a.clean_fields()
       except:
           self.fail("error!")
   ```

Comment: That worked, didn't know about those default values. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

> The force_insert parameter is documented elsewhere, but all it means is that a new object will always be created. Normally you won’t need to worry about this. However, if your model contains a manual primary key value that you set and if that value already exists in the database, a call to create() will fail with an IntegrityError since primary keys must be unique. Be prepared to handle the exception if you are using manual primary keys.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/

Don't use the create method. Also hopefully the function testFoo is a method for a TestCase.

I've had issues testing in the past aswell with sqlite3, try testing on postgres or mysql.

Comment: Using `create()` won't be a problem for him unless he's using manual primary keys. In any case, it's not related to his problem.